# Is there a tristate GUI element in YUI?

Tags: yui

I'm not seeing anything in YUI that could be used for a tristate GUI element.  Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are [radio buttons](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example04.html) and [menu buttons](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example07.html). Won't they do? What sort of presentation are you looking for?

Comment: I suspect something similar to this: http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/447/tristate.gif - I'm not familiar with one for YUI though.